# Using Mandrill for sending notification mails in PHP

Tags: php, email, mailchimp, newsletter, mandrill

Iam planning to send daily notification mails to my website users using Mandrill with PHP. I have some list of users in mailchimp lists and my database also. Now Iam following the method as sail in this link : http://lvsclasses.blogspot.in/2013/12/mandrill-api-to-send-mails-with.html. I tried to send mails as prescribed and it is working fine. But Iam not able to implement for loop based conditions for displaying the contents and also dont know hoow to send this mail to mailchimp lists.
 The documentations given by Mailchimp and Mandrill is not giving me an idea. Can you please help me to implement this requirement : sending notification mails to users(content is taking from website) and send to users in mailchimp list?